# Compare Long/Lat with Address in Database using Google Maps API

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Most tutorials I have seen on the Google Maps API simplly show you how to get your location and on it on a map.  That I get it.  But I want to take it one step further.

I want to:

(1) Get user's Long/Lat and (2) compare it to a list of addresses in the database;  then (3) return the closest address.  The database aspect is not the issue.  Just the Google Maps API.  (I use `php` for the DB stuff).

How would I do this?  (And am I correct in assuming that I need the Google API because the JavaScript built in Geolocation is not enough since addresses are involved?)

**EDIT:**

*I have revised my question to make it more specific.

How do you convert a street address to Long/Lat coordinates?*

Comment: If the addresses in your DB are coupled with lon/lat coordinates, then you don't even need Google API to calculate the closest address.

Comment: @HamZa  I actually have thought of this idea, but for this project, I am being requested to compare against actual address, not just the long/lat.  Is using the Google maps API to do this overkill?

Comment: Like I said, if you have the lat/lon then you don't need it. Note that the Google API has some daily request limit for free use.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3). It should get you started to get nearest coordinates. Please just don't use `mysql_`, use `mysqli` or `PDO` with prepared statements. What a shame for google teaching us deprecated functions ... Anyways, it's just the idea and you should obviously improve and edit it to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert a long/lat to an address and then calculate the distance of that address to other addresses, because you'd simply turn them back into long/lats to compare distances.

For each address in your database, you should also be storing the long/lat, which you can do once the address is entered.  This way, for each address, you're only making one call to Google's API to get the long/lat.  Then, compare the long/lat that was entered to those in your database to get the distance, and return the address that corresponds to the closets long/lat, and voila, you have the closest address.

Comment: What about simply converting an address to a a long/lat .. And nothing else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said :-). For each address in your database, you should convert it to a long/lat and store that information as well. This way, you can compare the distances by comparing the long/lat rather than trying to compare addresses with each other.